# Developing desktop app by python with cplex packages

Tags: python, api, runtime, cplex, docplex

I want to develop an app for my linear programming script in python, and when I installed python cplex API, and docplex that needed cplex optimisation studio to be installed in my computer.
my question is does the user need to install cplex optimisation studio to run my app ?

Comment: Depends on how you did it. In 99% of all cases, cplex is dynamically loaded and yes: the user somehow must acquire this too (e.g. by installing the full suite or maybe a community edition using pip -> which might not work for your problem). Of course, one might statically link cplex, but this has heavy license-related implications ("are you allowed to redist", and also build-tooling). Lots of different angles here. 1) If you can use the tool with the community-edition only. Ok. Should work for user too. 2) If you cannot, but need a commercial edition: Not ok. User will need to install it too.

Comment: Tanks for the answer. I actually create a small app that uses cplex package and try to run it in a a computer that doesn't have cplex studio installed in and it run.

Answer (score 0):

if the model is small enough you may install [CPLEX Community edition](https://www.ibm.com/account/reg/us-en/signup?formid=urx-20028) that is [free](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-free-ibm-cplex-alex-fleischer/). You may also install CPLEX.

If you do not want to install CPLEX:

You may also call CPLEX in [Cloudpakfordata](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/products/cloud-pak-for-data) through [WML](https://dataplatform.cloud.ibm.com/docs/content/wsj/analyze-data/ml-overview.html?context=cpdaas&audience=wdp) and then no need to install CPLEX. CPLEX will either be in the public cloud or in your private cloud

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my computer I use the no cost student edition. I create an app that uses cplex package and run it in another one with no cplex and it run